# Get variable from angular directive with isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `angular@1.6.3`, `bootstrap@3.3.7` and `jquery@1.12.4`.

I'm trying to wrap a `<select>` tag into [`bootstrap-multiselect`](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) jQuery plugin.

To do that, I'm trying to use custom directives with an isolated scope.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vc">
  <select multiple="multiple"
          multiselect
          ng-model="vc.selectedCountries"
          data-options="vc.allCountries"
          data-list-type="Countries">
      <optgroup ng-repeat="(continent, countries) in options" label="{{continent}}">
        <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.code}}">
        {{country.code}} - {{country.name}}
        </option>
      </optgroup>
  </multiselect>
</div>
```

And here is my JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  var self = this

  self.allCountries = {}

  $http.get('/countries.json')
    .then(function (result) {
      self.allCountries = result.data
    })
}])

app.directive('multiselect', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      options: '=',
      listType: '@',
    },
    transclude: true,
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$timeout', function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $timeout) {
      $scope.$watch('options', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log(newVal, oldVal)
        $timeout(function () {
          console.log($scope.options)
          $($element).multiselect('rebuild')
        }, 1)
      })

      $($element).multiselect()
    }]
  }
}])
```

However, this way the `<select>` is never populated.
This is not a problem with the plugin itself, because if I remove the lines containing `.multiselect()` calls, a regular multiselect appears empty.

I think it's something to do with transclusion and scope, because if I change     `transclude: true,` to `transclude: false,` and

```
<optgroup ng-repeat="(continent, countries) in options" label="{{continent}}">
```

to

```
<optgroup ng-repeat="(continent, countries) in vc.allCountries" label="{{continent}}">
```

it works just fine.

However, I'm trying to generalize this component, so I don't want to depend on the controller.

Comment: "Get a variable from angular directive with isolated scope", does it mean you want to access it somewhere in a different component?

Comment: Not quite. I'm building the stepping stones to generalize this component. The reason I want this is to not have a dependency from the controller in the internal `<option>` and `<optgroup>` tags, as the data will be injected through directive attributes.

Comment: So you don't want the data to be injected through directive attributes, which means it's not coming from your controller or rootScope?

Comment: So, what you're saying is that `data-options="vc.allCountries"` won't work?

Comment: It will work, but you won't be passing vc.allCountries value from a controller, but you will pass it directly with reference to $rootScope. Something you can write in your angular.config and pass it to this directive

Comment: Just to be sure: are you telling me that I can't use "controller as" syntax to make this work?

Comment: I'm sorry for the questions, but I'm very new to angular (1 week tops)

Comment: It's okay, initial stages of learning, this is how they go :). You can ask as many as you want. The controller as has nothing to do with the question you have, it's just an alias name that you put to your controller.

Comment: Just a disclaimer: `allCountries` is a property that is dinamically set by the controller. Will I still be able to set this through `angular.config`?

Comment: Sorry it's angular.run not config

Comment: You want to do a `<country-select/>` select directive? A directive that you can use it in every HTML? That's your point? Because is pretty simple to do. You have to populate the select inside your directive. I can give you an example if you confirm me that you want to do that...

Comment: @The.Bear I want to create a `multiselect` directive that wraps `bootstrap-multiselect` jquery plugin for `<select>` tags. It should be generalized, not specific for countries or whatsoever.

Comment: So do you want to have common select for every entity? I think if you want to do that the best approach is depend on services. You could use `$injector` inside the directive and pass service name as directive attribute. Put all arrays of options on `$rootScope` is really confused and if you have more than 10 select it could be a mess. I can give you an example later.

Answer (score 0):

You need not depend on your controller you have written in your code. You can try this alternative.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ng app</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            var myApp = angular.module('exampleApp', []);
            myApp.directive('highlight', function(){
                return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    console.log(scope.$root.list);
                }
            });

        myApp.run(function($rootScope){
           $rootScope.list = [1,2,3];
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <highlight listdata="$parent.list"></highlight>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about putting those thing on the root scope. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: we can make use of $transclude. Check this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/IbNqR0854V8yXnajKSFB?p=preview, it will give you a different approach. Please consider looking at only the directive part in the plunkr, as it has some controller also.